# WPML tables not deleted when removing multisite subsite, need help clearing up my sql-file!

Tags: multisite, database, sql, plugin-wpml

I´m building a WP Multisite for a client that wants a multilingual site. Before choosing WP Multisite, I bought and tried out WPML. However that plugin didn't fit for the job so I deleted it and got a refund.

However, now this seems to come back pestering me somehow. Now when using Multisite, I have been using Backupbuddy to export and duplicate my site for different testing purposes. Now some trouble has appeared, the database is friggin huge despite this being a very small page!

The SQL is a wooping 500 megs, I can't even see it in MyPhpAdmin. I got the SQL-file on my desk and when I finally got it open, its bloated everywhere with remnants of WPML tables that seems to have been duplicated with every site duplication, but never removed upon site deletion.

Has anyone encountered this? I´m no good at database editing and really unsure of how I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i wouldn't use phpmyadmin for a database that large. Use something like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) its free and easy to use.

Second if you dont want the tables that [WPML Created](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-tables/) and you have removed the plugin from your site you can remove the tables that it creates.

Upload the sql to a new database on your local machine and remove all this tables for each site:

```
wp_icl_cms_nav_cache
wp_icl_content_status
wp_icl_core_status
wp_icl_flags
wp_icl_languages
wp_icl_languages_translations
wp_icl_locale_map
wp_icl_message_status
wp_icl_node
wp_icl_reminders
wp_icl_strings
wp_icl_string_positions
wp_icl_string_status
wp_icl_string_translations
wp_icl_translate
wp_icl_translate_job
wp_icl_translations
wp_icl_translation_status
```

I assuming your prefix is **wp_(1,2,3)** and so on.